# Can I add a custom directive or custom HTML code to a marker's pop-up message?

Tags: ngx-leaflet

Can I add a custom directive or custom HTML code to a marker's pop-up message using ngx-leaflet?

Comment: ...Yes. Have you tried the documentation? Why not tell us more about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For adding non-Angular HTML to a marker's pop-up, you should be able to use setContent, which is a vanilla Leaflet method.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#popup-setcontent

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on this.